# Why didn't my rails app on heroku restart itself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I manage a rails app for a client of mine and recently it went down. The site was down for 9 hours before I noticed. I checked the logs and every request for the past 9 hours is prepended with the following code:

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"
```

Before that, I see the following logs:

```
2012-11-16T00:55:46+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2012-11-16T00:55:50+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2012-11-16T00:55:51+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-11-16 00:55:51] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
2012-11-16T00:55:51+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select'
2012-11-16T00:56:00+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2012-11-16T00:56:00+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2012-11-16T00:56:02+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2012-11-16T00:56:02+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2012-11-16T01:03:55+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2012-11-16T01:03:55+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2012-11-16T01:03:59+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 4303`
2012-11-16T01:04:00+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 98.139.241.251 - - [16/Nov/2012:01:04:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "YahooCacheSystem" domain.com
2012-11-16T01:04:22+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2012-11-16T01:04:22+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][11/16/12 01:04:21 +0000 b8af98a1-2246-4b34-9dfe-61b9d4b747bc (2)] INFO : Dispatcher: webrick
2012-11-16T01:04:22+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][11/16/12 01:04:21 +0000 b8af98a1-2246-4b34-9dfe-61b9d4b747bc (2)] INFO : Application: acsolar
2012-11-16T01:04:22+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][11/16/12 01:04:21 +0000 b8af98a1-2246-4b34-9dfe-61b9d4b747bc (2)] INFO : New Relic Ruby Agent 3.4.0.1 Initialized: pid = 2
2012-11-16T01:04:22+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2012-11-16T01:04:22+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.1.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:4303
2012-11-16T01:04:22+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2012-11-16T01:04:25+00:00 app[web.1]: [DEPRECATION] Your applications public directory contains an assets/products and/or assets/taxons subdirectory. 
2012-11-16T01:04:25+00:00 app[web.1]:     Run `rake spree:assets:relocate_images` to relocate the images.
2012-11-16T01:04:34+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][11/16/12 01:04:32 +0000 b8af98a1-2246-4b34-9dfe-61b9d4b747bc (2)] INFO : Reporting performance data every 60 seconds.
2012-11-16T01:04:34+00:00 app[web.1]: Connected to NewRelic Service at collector-5.newrelic.com
2012-11-16T01:05:00+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2012-11-16T01:05:00+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2012-11-16T01:05:02+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2012-11-16T01:05:02+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to down
2012-11-16T01:05:02+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I'm guessing that it may have spun down and had an error booting back up, but how come it stayed in the crashed state without restarting itself? Is there anything I can do to have it automatically restart if this happens again in the future?

I've got NewRelic running on this too and it didn't notify me at all, but that's another problem I'll have to investigate.

Comment: Is it the first time this is happening ? I encounter the same behavior  yesterday.

Comment: A few people encountered this same thing.  I don't know why but I would guess that the service that monitors dynos was failing.

Comment: Yeah, I got this too. I'd suggest trying the Papertrail add-on (they have a free plan). It immediately warned me when this happened.

Comment: Same problem occurred yesterday for the first time for me too. I'll open a ticket with Heroku if this is such a repeated issue and check back here.

Comment: Short question at all of you: Are you really using **WEBRick** as your application server. I remember seeing the same line this morning in my logs which is kind of weird as I use unicorn.

Comment: [Heroku Support Request](https://help.heroku.com/tickets/68349) linking to this thread sent.

Comment: ^ I don't think that request is publicly visible.

FWIW, I'm experiencing the same thing with a Clojure app beginning yesterday. The app appears to idle out (even after successfully serving requests seconds before) and then the next request 503's and logs Error H10.

Comment: I had a similar error after I updated a Rails 3.0 app to Rails 3.1 and started using the asset pipeline (that I wasn't very familiar with). Basically, in my instance, it was the asset compilation that was exceeding the maximum time limit.

Comment: I got a response from Heroku support. Apparently a process management error is/was causing some crashed apps only running 1 web dyno to be reported as "idle" even though they were actually crashed. They're implementing a fix. This may not directly address the question at hand, but it might be related.

Comment: Maybe you should also use an external monitoring tool - I use uptimerobot (http://www.uptimerobot.com/) to get an external view of all my hosted apps in case internal monitoring fails.

Comment: Good idea. NewRelic was supposed to do that, but it didn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heroku's support answer suggests restarting your app manually with `heroku restart`. They're fixing the issue right now.

> Hi, A process management error on our side caused some crashed apps
>   only running 1 web dyno to be reported as "idle" even though they were
>   actually crashed. This means that the crashed dyno was never
>   restarted, causing subsequent requests to fail. We've identified this
>   problem and are implementing a fix. If your app is still unresponsive,
>   please try restarting it with the heroku restart command. Please let
>   us know if you need more help. Thanks, Heroku Support

Comment: Hopefully they fix it soon. Restarting manually works, but we can't always be around to do that in a timely manner :p

Comment: is there any update on this? i still have this issue, where the server crashes and it does not seem to restart until i manually do this..